# Is Creating Ionic App for Android is Secure?

Tags: android, security, user-interface, ionic-framework

I am learning Ionic,I feel any one can steal our UI in ionic app,I seen by extracting our app apk,our UI is available in asset so Any one can crack our App UI from Asset.Is it Safe for our App UI when we build it in Ionic

Answer (score 0):

Like any html based mobile application, (so not only ionic) the assets do live in the apk and if you extract the files you can see the all the code as if it was a web app (that is basically what ionic is, obviously with all the goodies and Cordova etc..).
My suggestion would be to approach it as you would do for a web app, where the assets are in the customer browser, and choose one of the strategies that would work there. 
Personally, I would go with an obfuscation solution that makes your js files difficult enough to crack. No solution is perfect, but at least would deter the majority of malicious "reverse engineers".